# build a "fake" stake using startActivity()

Tags: java, android

I need to build a fake back stack in my application. I am starting an activity using aContext.startActivity(aIntent) and would like to build a stack to allow the user to go to the HomeActivity instead of exiting the application.

Now I know about the TaskStackBuilder but I am not sure on how to implement it when it comes to startActivity method.

This is what I got so far when building the stack but I am not sure how to use it in startActivity method

```
    Intent detailActivity = new Intent(aContext, DetailsActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(aContext);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(detailActivity);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix that i found to work without having to use onBackPressed was to add a flag to the intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `onBackPressed`

```
Context context = this;

@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start activity without adding to back stack, then override the onBackpressed

```
//Start activity without adding to history stack
Intent i = new Intent(...); // Your list's Intent
i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); // Adds the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag
startActivity(i);

//Override the newly open activity onBackPressed()
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For building fake stack use [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).This will help you to create back stack.

Suppose you activities are  'ActivityA', `ActivityB`, `ActivityC`, `ActivityD`. Now you are in `ActivityB` and from `ActivityB` you want launch `ActivityD` and want a back stack like this:

> ActivityA -> ActivityC -> ActivityD

That means back press from `ActivityD` will go to `ActivityC` and back press from `ActivityC` wil go to `ActivityA`

In `ActivityB` you can use this

```
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addParentStack(ActivityA.class)
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class))
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class))
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityD.class))
            .startActivities();
```

To use `TaskStackBuilder` you min sdk version should be 16 or higher.

For sdk less than 16 you can manually check in `onBackPressed` and start Activity.

**In Activity D:**

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

     if (extras.containsKey("FROM_ACTIVITY_B_FOR_STACK")){
        // start Activity C
     }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
     }

  }
```

Do this for other activities where you want to add back stack